# How to call javascript function from check box in ASP.NET?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to call Javascript function from Check box (Only client side), i tried following way but it is not working. can any one give answer?

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkAdd" runat="server"  OnClientClick="return validation();" OnCheckedChanged="btnAddMultiple_Click" AutoPostBack="true" />
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked your error console for JavaScript errors?

Comment: Are you getting an error?  Have you made sure that the script is included in the page properly?  Dev tools will help answer these questions.

Comment: Remove `AutoPostBack="true"`

Comment: remove the AutoPostBack="true". That causes an auto postback, as the name says.

Comment: javascript function is working fine..Thanks

Comment: AutoPostBack="true" is required in my application. Is there any posibility to use AutoPostBack="true" and client sid script?

Answer (score 5):

You want to **OnClick** event if you want to call javascript function.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkAdd" runat="server" OnClick="return validation();" 
    OnCheckedChanged="btnAddMultiple_Click" AutoPostBack="True" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validation() {
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to post back?")) {
            __doPostBack('<%= chkAdd.ClientID %>', '');
        } else {
            // Optional: change back the CheckBox to original position
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: How will it call the server side event on success?

Comment: @IrfanTahirKheli I do not know what the OP's intention. However, when one of the server control post back to server, **btnAddMultiple_Click** event'll also fire if the checked is changed. You only use **AutoPostBack="true"** if you want to fire **CheckedChanged** event immediately.

Comment: Please see my updated code which trigger the server side post back based on client side function.

Comment: it will not call server side event if you return false from the javascript function. @Win

Comment: @IrfanTahirKheli It is my intention. **return false** means user clicks on **Cancel button** at confirmation dialog. *I agree it is kind of confusing because OP did not say what javascript function is supposed to do. I hope 1612 get the idea.*